# Extracting Entity-Verb relations from open knowledge bases like Freebase and DBPedia

Tags: nlp, freebase, dbpedia, wordnet, wikidata

Is there any way that we can extract entity-verb relations from already existing online KBs like Freebase, DBPedia, Wikidata or Wordnet, I checked and only found that these sources concentrate on entities.

My aim is to derive relations like "A Person can Eat", "A Car can move", "A Man can play football".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into resources like these:

- [OpenCyc](http://sw.opencyc.org/concept/Mx4rvVjVcJwpEbGdrcN5Y29ycA)
- [VerbNet](http://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/vn/eat-39.1.php#eat-39.1-1)
- [FrameNet](https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frame/Ingestion.xml)
- [ConceptNet](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/web/c/en/eat) (somewhat of a successor to [Open Mind Common Sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Mind_Common_Sense))

Answer (score 1):

[ConceptNet](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/) is one of the source, [this link](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/web/c/en/football) shows all the concepts or facts related to football. These facts can be accessed by the API provided by conceptNet. Here is the [link](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/API). It provides three APIs - Lookup, search and association. Its a good source which is easy to use. You can configure it locally too.

[Opencyc](http://www.cyc.com/platform/opencyc) is also good resource. It can be set up locally too. They provide its download, onto this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencyc/files/). From both of these, I found ConceptNet more well maintained.

there is one more resource called [Probase](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/probase/). it can be used as common sense knowledge base, but I have not tried to configure it. I hope it helps :)